# Playwright not using the correct values from config file whilst running Mocha

Tags: mocha.js, playwright

I am building a test automation framework using JS + Playwright + Mocha and Chai. I have a problem where some values of the config files are ignored. For example the screenshot is defined to be taken only after failed tests, but it takes a screenshot after every test. I am using mocha to run the tests as in the following command:

```
"scripts":{
   "test":"mocha --recursive --timeout 100000 src/tests/*spec.js --reporter mocha-multi-reporters --reporter-options configFile=reporter.json"
}
```

Now, looking at the screenshot function which is defined in the `playwright.config.js`:

```
use: {
    screenshot: 'only-on-failure',
},
```

Everything seems fine, in theory.

However, now running the test with the following code:

```
afterEach(async function() {
    await page.screenshot({path: `screenshots/${new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10)}/${this.currentTest.title.replace(/\s+/g, '_')}.png`})
})
```

The screenshot is taken after every test. It should only take screenshots after failure.

Has someone experienced this?

Thanks

Comment: Hm. As far as i remember the "screenshot: 'only-on-failure'," will do screenshoot on failure.
But you have explicitly put screenshot after each, comment that code, and you will have it only on failure. 
Understand the difference between built in screen shot, and explicitly called screen shot.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. However, removing screenshot function after afterEach function did not solve the problem. For some reason running tests with Mocha was messing up the config settings. I found a solution by migrating to the new Playwright Test Runner which solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was solved by migrating to the new Playwright Test Runner from Mocha.

Then the following code works:

```
use: {
    screenshot: 'only-on-failure',
},
```

This allows me to avoid running screenshot function in the afterEach hook. And produces a screenshot to a test-results folder.